# code for tooltip to hide after 3 sec works fine for first time only unless i reload the page.I think the hover function is executed once only

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-tooltip

```
$('#example').hover(function() {
setTimeout(function(){$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide'); },3000);
```

}

Here's js fiddle link:- https://jsfiddle.net/akshandilya/8qmgnpb1/2/

Comment: You don't have a hover event listener, and setTimeout only runs once

Comment: i added hover but still not working...

Comment: Take a look at the console you have an error due to a typo

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to the hover.  If you test it again, but wait three seconds before hovering, you'll notice it doesn't even work the first time.  The timer executes 3 seconds AFTER the document has loaded.  Here is how you should modify it:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
$('a').hover(function()  {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
  },3000);
});
```

This way, the timeout happens AFTER the hover actually has begun.

Comment: still not working...I have updated the fiddle if you could see

Comment: The javascript looks the same as before, I don't see my suggestion implemented in it.  Also, I've updated my answer with a fixed version of your code.  However, the element you're selecting $("#example") doesn't actually appear to exist on the html document.

Comment: Update, I changed your selector to "a", and it works perfectly!